# jdbc connection string with c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, c3p0

I have jdbc configured with c3p0.
However, I am worried about possible conflicts, since some of the parameters in jdbc string and c3p0 are similar.

Here is my jdbc string:

```
jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1:3306/db?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&connectTimeout=15000&socketTimeout=30000&autoReconnect=true
```

We decided to include connectTimeout, socketTimeout, autoReconnect
because otherwise it took too long to switch to the replica if master crashes. ( We are using MySQL RDS Multi-AZ ).

Here are my c3p0 properties:

```
<property name="acquireIncrement" value="3"/>
<property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
<property name="maxIdleTime" value="3600"/>
<!--  1 hour  -->
<property name="maxConnectionAge" value="7200"/>
<property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="600"/>
<property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="180"/>
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"/>
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false"/>
```

Any ideas / suggestions?
Maybe someone has production-ready configuration?

Best Regards,
Maksim

Comment: There's no conflict. These parameters look fine, as long as your application can tolerate the occasional, rare case where in the 3 minute window while Connections are idle and untested, something goes wrong (e.g. the database goes down) and the client sees a bad Connection. If you never want the client to see a bad Connection no matter what, use `testConnectionOnCheckout`, but that carries a client-visible performance cost. Also, you are probably fine, but make sure that you are using c3p0-0.9.5+ and a JDBC4+ driver that supports Connection.isValid(). if not define a `preferredTestQuery`.